# How do upgrade to GWT 2.5 in Eclipse

Tags: gwt, eclipse-juno, gwt-2.5

I'm using GWT 2.4 & Eclipse Juno. GWT is installed using the instructions at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse.

I'd like to try GWT 2.5.

How do I upgrade from GWT 2.4 to 2.5?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, GWT 2.5 is only available as a Release Candidate, and as such is not delivered via the usual Eclipse update site yet. However, it's easy to use Eclipse with any GWT version:

- Download the GWT SDK(s) you need from https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/versions
- Extract it anywhere you like
- In Eclipse Preferences > Google > Web Toolkit, use the "Add..." button and navigate to the GWT SDK directory

Then, in each Eclipse project's properties page (Project > Properties > Google > Web Toolkit), you can choose one of your installed SDKs.

Comment: Can't find it via the update site even after the final release of 2.5.0 ... anything I'm missing?

Comment: @pong: I'd generally recommend downloading and installing it separately. Nothing about the GWT SDK is Eclipse-specific, so using the Eclipse update site to install the SDK is basically just a convenient "getting started" way. (2.5.0 was released only 2 days ago. I assume that they will re-build the Eclipse update site soon.)

Comment: Thx! Can you elaborate on the benefits of a separate install? Read this hint elsewhere, too, but don't get the point. I will only ever develop in Eclipse, and using the update site I'll be notified of updates automatically: does the recommendation still apply in this case?

Comment: @pong: Generally, the advantage of a separate download (or a download via Maven) is, that you may want to put the SDK into your company's repository, use it in automated builds and tests etc. It's often important, that everyone uses the exact same version of a library, as opposed to a version that some team members may have updated to from the Eclipse update site or not.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I'm a one-man-show so I'll stick to the update site method (as soon as it's available ...), though :)

Comment: @pong FYI: GWT SDK v2.5.0 is available on the update site now.

Comment: All thumbs up - as long as you keep notifying me of updates I could as well give the standalone installation a try ;)