# GWT 2.5. Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt-2.5

How I can install GWT 2.5 into Eclipse Juno? In GWT's update site located only 2.4 SDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do upgrade to GWT 2.5 in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691575/how-do-upgrade-to-gwt-2-5-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

You just need to install the GWT plugin for eclipse from (using  eclipse `Install new software`) [dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2)

then manually download GWT SDK from http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list

and choose this SDK in Eclipse-preferences-Google-WebToolkit-SDK

Answer (score 0):

2.5 has not yet been released, so there's no Eclipse plugin yet.

Comment: Meanwhile, the Eclipse plugin SDK version 2.6 is available, and yet, I cannot see 2.5 as a plugin (only 2.6). Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: No. Only the latest version is available as an Eclipse plugin (AFAIK). If you want 2.5, then download the ZIP file from https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list and point Eclipse to it: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/using_sdks

Comment: Ok, but ... my target framework is GWT 2.5; do I need the *SDK* of version 2.5 to develop for/with GWT 2.5, or is the SDK 2.6 backwards-compatible to previous GWT versions (in which case my comment would be irrelevant)?

Comment: 2.6 is mostly backwards-compatible with 2.5: http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html