# LibGDX and GWT - Error 404

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, libgdx, jetty

We've recently been trying to use LibGDX to convert our LibGDX app into a web app. However, whenever we try to run the application we just get a HTML Error 404 and this error code in Eclipse:

```
[WARN] Server class 'org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner'     
    could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/adt-bundle 
   windows-x86_64 
   20140702/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0/gwt-
   2.6.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
```

Despite seeing this a lot on various websites, there have been no useful answers yet.

PS - Please answer in plain English - we're pretty new to this!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - turns out our installation of GWT was a bit broken. We found that following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691575/how-do-upgrade-to-gwt-2-5-in-eclipse%22here%22) worked better!